# How to change a global variable name in an Excel VBA project?

Tags: vba, excel, global-variables

If someone have to carry on working on an Excel VBA project/module after the previous developer left the company, **how do they safely change a global variable name**?

These global variable names can be problematic if they are misleading, misspelled, look like another variable, don't follow the chosen convention, etc.

Changing them with a Search/Replace is a problem because sometimes it's a word that appears in comments.

Changing them by Copy/Pasting is a problem because it's long and you can miss some, especially if there are a lot of occurrences or if you change it to something similar.

**Is there a way to do this safely via the Excel "IDE", or via another tool?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need to do here is called a *refactoring* - you need to make a possibly dangerous change to the code, without affecting its behavior. Do it wrong and the code breaks!

Renaming an identifier that's used in one or more places, is a *rename* refactoring.

Most modern IDE's have such a feature (and several other *refactorings*). However the VBE was at the height of its glory well before Visual Studio was the full-featured tool it has become since then - heck, the VBE *was* Visual Studio (6.0) in 1998!

So you really have two options:

- **Do the refactoring manually** - the IDE's *search & replace* functionality (Ctrl+H) can be dangerous here, because it treats code as simple text, without semantic understanding: you need to review every single occurrence individually, or risk renaming an identifier that was not referring to the variable you're trying to rename.
- **Use a 3rd-party tool** - I don't know any VBIDE add-ins that understand the code deeply enough to allow safely refactoring VBA code, other than the open-source [**Rubberduck**](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) project, which I've managed since October 2014). This add-in parses your entire project, builds a symbol table, and lets you navigate and, yes, *refactor/rename* any identifier, automatically updating all call sites.

[image: Rubberduck's rename refactoring at work]

Note that Rubberduck is a very active open-source project, constantly improving. Parsing VBA is *hard*, and getting the VBE functionally on par with modern-day IDEs isn't a small undertaking, nor is it easy... but it's *fun*, and yep, it works.

Comment: I still have yet to install Rubberduck, but it's on my short list. I have used MZ Tools' search and replace feature to change such items, always being careful that the search is constrained to find whole words with matching capitalization, etc., to prevent inadvertent changing of something else.

Comment: @JonPeltier that can work, but you still have to carefully review each replacement individually - because if you have e.g. `Module1.Foo` and `Module2.Foo`, search & replace will not be able to tell the difference, but a *rename* refactoring will ;-)

Comment: Sure. I try not to have duplicate Foos in different modules, and I do review the list of items found before I replace them. But you're right, it's potentially disastrous.

Comment: @JonPeltier bad example maybe... variables that have the same name as some member in a referenced library would be another. That said, I'm currently having some serious issues with the "autocompletion" feature, so you'll probably want to wait for the official next 2.3.0 stable release, rather than try the much outdated 2.2.0 or an unstable pre-release build =)